# Understanding usb busses devices and ports

Tags: usb-device

I have some over-current error messages in `dmesg` output.

```
[    2.235648] usb 4-1-port3: over-current condition
[    2.443643] usb 4-1-port4: over-current condition
```

If I do an `lsusb -s 4:1` I get the following

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

but can't seem to find out anything more.

Have I correctly associated the 4-1 in the `dmesg` output with bus 4 device 1, or does it mean something different.

Ultimately - what I really want to know, is my hardware broken and can I perhaps disconnect something and reconnect it to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by damaged usb port/s. You haven't mentioned if it is usb 2.0 or usb 3.0 ports which you have.

A similar query was raised at https://askubuntu.com/questions/147555/over-current-condition-on-port-7-or-8 and the answer I guess would be same.

The fixture would be replace the motherboard/usb hub or whatever it is that has the usb port.

Comment: They are usb2.0 ports.  I have a number of usb ports at the front of my chassis, and I think one of them isn't working, so that is the likely cause.  Before I start taking my hardware to pieces, though, I wanted to check how they mapped across - hence asking if the 4-1 in the dmesg output meant bus 4 device 1, or something different